# sqlite works on simulators but not on device

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

My app makes some database connections (sqllite) and performs some basic database operations (insert,delete,search),I wrote some code for this,Its worked perfectly in simulator but not in phone,Can any one help overcome this ,Thanks in advance.I used follwing code to insert data,I already add the code to create database and tables.
And I create Folder SDCard in my application's folder,

```
public void insertInTotblFavStationList(String url,String StationName,String imageUrl,String bitRate,String formats){
        try {
            URI uri = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/myDb.db");
            Statement statement =null;
            Database grabDB = null;
            grabDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
            statement = grabDB.createStatement("insert into tblFavStationList(url,StationName,StationImage,Bitrate,Formats) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
            statement.prepare();
            statement.bind(1, url);
            statement.bind(2, StationName);
            statement.bind(3, imageUrl);
            statement.bind(4, bitRate);
            statement.bind(5, formats);         
            statement.execute();
            statement.close();
            grabDB.close();
            System.out.println("ins");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work on the device?

Comment: I actaully got an exception:net.rim.device.api.database.DatabasePathException: Invalid path name. Path does not contains a proper root list. See FileSystemRegistry class for details.

Comment: I create a menu retreive data from table,and it displys in a list field,I got that list as empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that when my BB is connected to my Macbook EVEN IF USB filesharing is off the SDCard seems to be mounted. This means that any database files stored there are inaccessible and will throw "Invalid path name".

Check whether your SDCard is mounted by going to the camera app, if it is it will give you a warning that you can't save photos.

Try loading your app and then disconnecting the USB. It's a pain because it means you can't properly debug.

Answer (score 0):

SQLLite only works on blackberries versión 5 and up. What phone's model are you using? it may be your problem. Also could you post the error your phone throws?

I also could be related to code signing. SQLite requires you to code sign your application It is not required for the simulator but it is for your phone. It's because of the API it uses to operate. [Code Sign](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp)

Comment: I am using blackberry version 5, I tested in the phone Blackberry Bold 9000

Comment: I got a similar problem because of the path name, it has to be "SDCard"... example: String dbpath = "/SDCard/databases/";

Comment: Try with: URI uri = URI.create("/SDCard/Databases/myDb.db"); and then to open the database add "file://"